# vue radio boxes returning string instead of boolean

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a reusable radio box that is supposed to return true or false depending on which radio box is selected. the problem is that it returns a string instead of a boolean and I have no idea why this behavior is so.

below is the parent component that calls the radio component

```
<radioinput name="yes" :value="true" v-model="form.time.alwaysopen">Yes</radioinput>
<radioinput name="no" :value="false" v-model="form.time.alwaysopen">No</radioinput>

form: {
    time: {
        alwaysopen: true,
        open: null,
        close: null
    }
}
```

below is the radio component that is called

```
<template>
    <label :for="name" class="inline-form radio">
        <slot></slot>
        <input type="radio" :name="name" :id="name" class="radio-input" :checked="isChecked" :value="value" @change="$emit('change', $event.target.value)">
        <div class="radio-radio"></div>
    </label>
</template>

export default {
    model: {
        prop: 'modelValue',
        event: 'change'
    },
    props: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        value: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true
        },
        modelValue: { 
            type: Boolean,
        },
    },
    computed: {
        isChecked() {
            return this.modelValue == this.value
        }
    }
}

Please what could be the issue?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you emit the `change` event from your radio component, you're taking `$event.target.value`, which is the [`HTMLInputElement.value` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) that is always a string. In order to emit the boolean `value` prop itself, you should refer to it directly in the `@change` handler like this:

```html
<input type="radio" :name="name" :id="name" class="radio-input" :checked="isChecked" :value="value" @change="$emit('change', value)">
```